# How can I send a picture from my computer to my Discord Bot w/ Python

Tags: python, discord

This is my first time posting a help request/question on this website, I've seen that the community is helpful.

I'm a newbie into Python scripting. I currently got a music player's bot template, so I could start learning messing up with the notepad++, and python.

I've seen how you can post the picture, by doing `client.send_file(channel,Picture)`.

I tried just put in picture the file's `location(picture)`, and it said that it wasn't defined.

I tried also let picture, and try create something defining Picture.

```
def Pic1 'C:\Users\Norberto\Documents\NMusicBot\Pictures\MyPic1.jpg'
```

It gives me a Syntax error.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Maybe this is simple to solve, but I can't figure out how to fix this!

Regards,

Norby.

Comment: What on earth is `"def Pic1 'C:\Users\Norberto\Documents\NMusicBot\Pictures\MyPic1.jpg'"` ?

Comment: My friend said that for do like that, and then just send the picture by doing "Pic1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it.
The location of the file usually is something like "C:\Users\Something", while writting the location in the script, you need to add the '\' twice, something like: "C:\Users\Something".

For send it, it's just Client.send_file(location).

You can also create a 'shortcut' for it, by doing "Pic1 = C:\Users\Something" and then, "Client.send_file(Pic1).